# Переменную в файл с сохранением форматирования

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Всем привет, подскажите как записать в bash скрипте переменную в файл с сохранением форматирования ?

На первой картинке код скрипта с переменной, на второй то как она записывается в файл

[image: Image first]
[image: Image second]

Comment: Не используйте shell для таких задач.

Comment: /отвлечённо/ как иногда хочется, чтобы на главной странице была надпись большими красными мигающими буквами «не пости скриншот, если можно скопировать текст»... /по теме/ используй `heredoc`, за подробностями прошу в гугл или переоформи нормально вопрос...

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы интерпретатор не производил подстановок в строке **при её присвоении переменной**, строку надо заключить в одинарные кавычки `'`, а не в двойные `"`:

```
$ a='.$x.' b=".$x."; echo "$a $b"
.$x. ..
```

если внутри строки надо поместить одинарную кавычку, в этом месте надо сделать разрыв строки и в него поместить символ:

```
$ c='...'\''...'; echo $c
...'...
```

---

но проще будет использовать [*heredoc*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (с ограничивающей строкой, заключённой в одинарные или двойные кавычки), сохранив в переменную:

```
v=$(cat << 'endoftext'
    $x
endoftext
)
echo $v
```

или сразу в файл

```
cat > файл << "endoftext"
     $x
endoftext
```

Comment: *EOF* стандарт де факто вместо не очень читабельного *"endoftext"* (обратите внимание также на отсутствие кавычек в часто используемом случае.